# How to color the <li> counters in addition to their contents?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to be able to style the whole row - number included - as a single element.

I've tried "list-style-position: inside", but makes text appear below the number, so it won't work.

Is there a way to do achieve the desired result?

Here is a code snippet to portray the issue. I want numbers to stay in the red box and stay aligned to a single line as they currently are:

```css
ol { 
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li> Text
    <li> Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very, Very Long Text
    <li> Text
</ol>
```

Comment: Assuming the literal ordered list in your question is showing how you want it... it sounds like you don't need to make any changes. As the Stack Snippet I just created shows, the default display properties of such code will make your content appear as you say you want it.

Comment: @TylerH I've updated the code snippet to better explain the desired result.

Comment: I understand you want to target just a single li (and the li's number, e.g. "2."). That much of the question is a duplicate for sure and the question shouldn't be reopened for that. But the part of your question that isn't clear is the "*all text is aligned to a single line - it's not supposed to appear under the numbers.*" The behavior you are describing as not supposed to be happening is *already not happening*.

Comment: @TylerH I want to target all lis. I want behavior A (aligned to a line) and B (rows styled as a single element / number kept in the red box) to happen at the same time. In the question, A is happening, but B is not.

Comment: OK, so then I'm not sure why you bother mentioning something not working when it is. I will edit the question to make it more clear, but again #2 is a duplicate so the question should not be reopened (because it will just get closed again as a duplicate).

Comment: @TylerH Thanks for editing the question. I'm not sure what do you mean by #2. To clarify, If I didn't mention that I also want A, then "list-style-position: inside" would be a valid answer to just B, but would break the formatting in A at the same time and keep the issue. That's why I believe that it's hard to find a duplicate of [A and B] together -.separate answers to A and B don't have to give an answer to [A and B].

Comment: I mean literally the 2nd list item in your ordered list... the one that starts with `2.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220933/discussion-between-ambu-and-tylerh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `:nth-of-type` selector to select the specific row i.e:

```
li:nth-of-type(2) { 
    color: blue; 
}
```

For styling the numbers you'd have to set `list-style: none` and then make use of the CSS properties `counter-reset` and `counter-increment` to set a number (with an associated name) and increment that number, allowing you to style it however you want:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: my-counter;
  list-style: none;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) { 
  color: blue; 
}

li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) ". ";
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}

li:nth-of-type(2)::before {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Numbers</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! I only had to add: li { display: flex; } for it to work as intended!